# SELECT that returns list of values not present in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

query:

```
select id from users where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

If the users table contains ids 1, 2, 3, this would return 1, 2, and 3. I want a query that would return 4 and 5. In other words, I don't want the query to return any rows that exist in the table, I want to give it a list of numbers and get the values from that list that don't appear in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the [MINUS](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/minus.php) operator. You can also use this along with `odcinumberlist` without having to store your values in a temporary table

```
SELECT column_value
FROM table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5)) 
MINUS
SELECT ids
FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to represent your list of numbers as a relation (probably not exactly the term Oracle docs would use, but...)

```
VALUES 1,2,3,4,5
```

Then you could use this in a query in a number of ways

```
SELECT *
 FROM (VALUES 1,2,3,4,5) as V(A)
WHERE A NOT IN ( -- query your table here
                   )
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES 1,2,3,4,5) as V(A)
     LEFT JOIN -- your table
        ON V.A = table.column
 WHERE table.column is NULL
```

or

```
VALUES 1,2,3,4,5
 MINUS
 -- query your table
```

I'm not at a computer with ORacle installed, so any of these may be a bit off on syntax, but the ideas are there...